# Anyone experienced in Gaming/Gambling industry?

Tags: legal

Are there any legal hassles when you work in these Casino kinds of industry? I'm offered a job and I like it owing to clever algorithms and multi-threaded enviornment. I'd like some advice on legal issues before taking the offer.

*Ok I'm not going to sue any one of you for bad advice. I just wanted to know if people have any experience in such affairs. And I'm not looking for a lawyer's advise at all, I'm trying to know the gaming industry trends in general and what the programmers there have to say about their work when it comes to gamblings. And how would the lawyer know what goes inside the casino programming industry?
*

Comment: What kind of legal advice are you looking for specifically?

Comment: Don't look for legal advice on the interweb. Find a lawyer who provides a free half hour or hour session and ask them.

Comment: @Demian Brecht - Why is it that the word "legal" scares everyone around here? Even if answers do not give certain answers, they will surely point the OP in the right direction.

Comment: "Legal" scares people because people get sued over bad or misunderstood legal advice. Lawyers are much less likely to make mistakes like those and have recourse to deal with such things.

Comment: @World Engineer - Right. And lawyers were born with knowledge of law. Just like people ask for technical advice, they should not be afraid of asking for legal advice. Not all of it will be correct, but they'll learn something out of it. People get sued over technical screw-ups as well.

Comment: @rook  "Legal" scares people because laws are different from country to country, from state to state, from city to city.  Even within one jurisdiction, legal requirements are often murky and full of conflicting case law, making a clear and definitive answer impossible, and certainly not applicable a week from now.  "Legal" answers, even assuming that they're clearly and unambiguously correct for the person providing the answer, won't necessarily be correct for the person who asked the question.  Or for someone else who's found this question from Google, a year later.

Comment: @DoomedBunnies - Most of that can be said for technical rules as well. But the fundamentals of law are well founded, and known. If we take the distinction between anglosaxon and continental law which is based on Roman, the rest are practically details. And no, laws are not "murky" - they are well defined for specific cases. For those cases that they're not defined, you referr to above "fundamentals". Study of certain laws is maybe complex, but not complicated an issue, and I don't understand the fear over it. But hey ... ignorance is bliss for some, so to each his own.

Comment: @rook - Really don't appreciate being called "ignorant", thanks.  If that wasn't your intention, then please disregard.  Either way, I still stand behind my original comment.

Comment: In many places, giving legal advice is considered "practicing law", and it's illegal to do so without the proper license. In the US, the [definition](http://www.americanbar.org/content/dam/aba/migrated/cpr/model-def/model_def_statutes.authcheckdam.pdf) varies by state. In any case, I (for example) could get in serious trouble if I gave legal advice, even if everything I said was correct *and* the person I gave it to was happy with the results and didn't sue me or anything on that order.

Comment: What kind of hassles are you afraid of?

Comment: @jerry: Giving pointers isn't illegal though.

Comment: @Anna: I don't know. Just trying to figure them out.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin - No one in here is giving legal advice (btw, "advice on legal issues" is not "legal advice"), as far as I can see, nor have I seen anyone breach the institute of law practice. I've read your document, and I don't see that the institute has been breached in any of the states.

Comment: I didn't intend to say anybody *had* offered legal advice -- only pointing out that there are really good reasons for people to be extremely careful that they don't.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for very specific legal advice that we cannot provide. Please read [What types of legal questions are on-topic here?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/1655/88986) and [When is a software licensing question on topic?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7265/88986)

Answer (score 3):

I once did some freelance work for a bookie that wanted to integrate to BetCris to get the latest lines for his clients from his website.

Every industry needs software, even gambling industry.

Most of the time, its the gambling aspect that needs legal advice.  For example, in my state, bookies are illegal, but running his operations offshore is perfectly legal.  As a programmer, I just wrote the code.  In my case, my code was uploaded to a server somewhere offshore where the it was legal, so there wasn't any issues.

I think the biggest takeways are:

Is your client operating legally in regards to gambling and following state and federal laws.  If so, I think you have nothing to worry about.  If not, then you are particapating and aiding in an illegal operation.  So just make sure your "client" is following the rules.

The other thing is the morality of the whole thing.  Some people may frown upon working in industries such as gambling, pornagraphy, etc.  I never lost sleep over it even though I was enabling his gambling operations, but to me it was just another paying client.

*This isn't legal advice.  I am not a lawyer.  These are my experiences working in the gambling industry.  Sueing me would be pointless and not profitable.  :)

Comment: Thanks Jon. Real men don't sue:) Any idea how to find that your client is "operating legally in regards to gambling and following state and federal laws".

Comment: @Jon Raynor - Nice disclaimer in the end :))))

Comment: @Mr Zen - Check the laws in your local area. If you are concerned, the best advice I can give you is to hire a lawyer to do the legwork.  In my case, I just made sure the code was uploaded offshore by checking out his hosting provider.  Once I knew it was in country X where is was legal, I felt comfortable.